# C3JS: Plotting the stacked bar chart with different points on upper and lower part

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, c3.js

In c3js stacked bar chart, i am trying to create two staged graph having y-axis with different points. But i didnt find the different points plots each other.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    columns: [
        ['data1', -30, 200, 200, 400, -150, 250],
        ['data2', 130, 100, -100, 200, -150, 50],
        ['data3', -230, 200, 200, -300, 250, 250]
    ],
    type: 'bar',
    groups: [
        ['data1', 'data2']
    ]
},
grid: {
    y: {
        lines: [{value:0}]
    }
}
});
```

In the above code, my upper part of yaxis should start from 200 and lower part should from 100. please someone guide me to solve this.